# Prevent a modal button to submit the form it is in

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The issue:

I have Bootstrap modal buttons in a form that open a modal to select data (users and cost types), these buttons are not meant to submit the main form.

When I press the modal buttons the modal opens only when other required fields are empty.
When the required fields are filled in by a user the form submits (this is not hat I expect).

How can I prevent the form from submitting when trying to open a modal?

`e.preventDefault();` does not prevent the form from submitting.

A jsfiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/cagy79/193thboq/

Any ideas?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is full of errors. Look at the console.

Comment: Yes I know, first time i used it, took me 30 minutes just to get this fiddle working a little bit :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add an input type of "button" to your HTML. Then you don't need your dontSubmit class.

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddStaff" type="button" >
```

The reason this is: In HTML5,any button without a type defaults to a "submit" type.

Hope that helps!